# Why does my Index of Directory shown if I access my website

Tags: reactjs, laravel

In the past month I work on pure php laravel framework which the project is already done and running on live. This month our team asking for **revising the project to reactjs with laravel php framework.** Which the development stage is already done this past few weeks. Our team trying to deploy in production in which they encounter one problem when we access the website Ex. www.myproject.com the page show the root project folder it look like this.

**Note: That my project is fresh and we not configure anything to htaccess.**

[image: error]

**The scenario before i deploy the project:.**

1. npm install

then

2. npm run production

   to get the final index.js file which will contain all the code bundled
   [image: Compiled]

**Package.json:**
[image: package.json file]

Webpack.config.js
[image: Webpack]

Web server

[image: Web server]

Comment: You need to configure your webserver's document root to point at the `public` directory.

Comment: hi @ceejayoz this problem is in our server? not in my codes? or we need to configure in htaccess?

Comment: Correct, you need to adjust your webserver's configuration.

Comment: ceejay can i ask what should need to do in webserver config?

Comment: See my first comment.

Comment: @ceejayoz thanks ceejay, i will try this thank you.. i give update if it working now.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/185391/discussion-between-devge-and-ceejayoz).

Comment: @ceejayoz we already configure the web server. kindly please look the update.

Comment: If you're using Apache, `DocumentRoot` is what you want to be tweaking.

Comment: what do you mean for that ceejay??

Comment: Exactly what I said. You need to set your Apache `DocumentRoot` properly, to point to the `public` directory of your Laravel app.

Answer (score -1):

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
    ServerName appname.com
    ServiceAlias www.appname.com
    DocumentRoot /var/www/appname/public

    <Directory "/var/www/appname/public">
            Options FollowSymLinks
            ReWriteEngine On
    </Directory>

    ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
    CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined
</VirtualHost>
```

[Source](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49184358/setting-document-root-for-laravel-project-on-apache-virtual-host)