# Two forms on single page, one doesn't work in laravel

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5.6

I have two contact forms on same page (bootstrap modal window). The problem is that one of them doesn't work correctly and return `404 Not Found` error.

I have this in `web.php`

```
Route::post('/b2b_contact','HomeController@b2b_contact')->name('b2b_contact');
Route::post('/','HomeController@contact')->name('contact');
```

`HomeController.php` functions

```
public function contact(Request $request)
{ 

    $data = array(
        'first_name' => $request->first_name,
        'company_name' => $request->company_name,
        'country'  => $request->country,
        'email'  => $request->email,
    );

    DB::table('contact')->insert($data);         
    return Redirect::to('/')->with('message', 'Thank you!');
}

public function b2b_contact(Request $request)
{ 

    $data = array(
        'first_name' => $request->first_name,
        'company_name' => $request->company_name,
        'country'  => $request->country,
        'email'  => $request->email,
    );

    DB::table('b2b_contact')->insert($data);         
    return Redirect::to('/')->with('message', 'Thank you!');
}
```

And what I have in the blade template are the forms

```
{{Form::open(array('route'=>'b2b_contact','files' => true,'method'=>'post', ))}}

// input fields here

{{Form::close()}}  

{{Form::open(array('route'=>'contact','files' => true,'method'=>'post', ))}}

// input fields here

{{Form::close()}}
```

The second form `contact` works perfectly but the `b2b_contact` return Error 404.

I've also tried to make both routes in web.php like `Route::post('/',....` but then the page return error that `b2b_contact` route isn't find.

So, can anyone help me here how to have 2 contact forms on same page and when they are submitted to reload the page and show the success message?

UPDATE: this is what I see when I submit the page and yes, debug is set to true

> ## Not Found
>
> The requested URL /applyNow was not found on this server.
>
> Additionally, a 404 Not Found error was encountered while trying to use an ErrorDocument to handle the request.

UPDATE 2: `.htaccess` file in public directory

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    <IfModule mod_negotiation.c>
        Options -MultiViews -Indexes
    </IfModule>

    RewriteEngine On

    # Handle Authorization Header
    RewriteCond %{HTTP:Authorization} .
    RewriteRule .* - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%{HTTP:Authorization}]

    # Redirect Trailing Slashes If Not A Folder...
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} (.+)/$
    RewriteRule ^ %1 [L,R=301]

    # Handle Front Controller...
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]
</IfModule>
```

Comment: Anything in Laravel logs?

Comment: Nothing in the log

Comment: Do you have debug enabled in `.env`? Can you put `dd(1)` at the top of `b2b_contact` method and retry to submit a form? Than tell me if you get `1` in browser.

Comment: I've updated my question with screenshot of the page.

Comment: Do you have more routes, specifically a `GET` route for `/`

Comment: Yes, one more - `Route::get('/','HomeController@index');` for the main page

Comment: The error doesn't look like it went through laravel (perhaps a wrong domain). Also the URL is `/applyNow` which isn't visible in your code. How/Where are you navigating to `/applyNow`?

Comment: I just tried to change the `b2b_contact` .. just in case if Laravel doesn't like it

Comment: The URL is `http://localhost/b2b_contact` is not wrong. I mean I don't have blade with that name, but I don't think I need one since I redirect back to home page

Comment: But your screenshot says `The requested URL /applyNow was not found on this server`

Comment: It was just for a test, I've changed `b2b_contact` everywhere with `applyNow` and after that I've put it back `b2b_contact`.

Comment: I've tried to put `index.php` in the url `Route::post('/index.php/b2b_contact','HomeController@b2b_contact')->name('index.php/b2b_contact');` and I've got the native laravel 404 error page, but I don't see the 1 from `dd(1)` on it.

Comment: What is your application root directory? Are you executing laravel via Apache or `php artisan serve`?

Comment: Okay, I've found something strange. If I load the site with this URL `https://example.com/index.php` and then open the form and submit it -> it's works perfectly. If I open the site without index.php `https://example.com/` and submit the form,  I've got 404 error.

Comment: it is via Apache

Comment: You need to adapt Apache in order to allow Laravel's router to work: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49184358/setting-document-root-for-laravel-project-on-apache-virtual-host

Comment: What happens if you run your project with `php artisan serve` from the command line? It's working then, right?

Comment: @Johannes, no, error 500 because `[Fri Apr 12 15:53:45 2019] PHP Warning:  require_once(/var/www/html/public/index.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in /var/www/html/server.php on line 21`

Comment: But what about if on shared hosting for example godaddy.. the apache should be okay there?

Comment: How is your directory called ?

Comment: Have a look at this .htaccess example here: https://laravel.com/docs/master#web-server-configuration

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tried your setup locally with Laravel 5.8 and XAMPP. When I copy the Laravel project to `/htdocs` then my path to the Laravel home page is `/htdocs/public`. In the browser I have to enter `http://localhost/public/` or I need to change the Apache config to, for example, provide the public folder via `laravel.local`.

Having this setup described above and clicking on the form link your browser tries to POST to this URL: `http://localhost/b2b_contact` - this is not existing because we need to POST to `http://localhost/public/b2b_contact`.

**Why is it working for `/contact` and not for `/b2b_contact`?**

In your routes file you define the routes as follows:

```
Route::post('/b2b_contact','HomeController@b2b_contact')->name('b2b_contact');
Route::post('/','HomeController@contact')->name('contact');
```

The `/contact` route isn't even called `contact` but `/` - that is your vhosts root directory. According to your comment on your initial post your Laravel installation (`vendor` folder etc.) seems to be located inside of `/var/www/html` and you are calling your `public` directory. I'm not 100% sure about this but please try to fix your directory structure.

Comment: The problem was in the .htaccess and the redirects. Thanks.