# 404 error when deploying Laravel app (created with Voyager and Voyager Front-End) to Google Cloud Compute Engine, Ubuntu 18.04

Tags: laravel, git, google-compute-engine, ubuntu-18.04, voyager

I have installed Laravel, Voyager, and Voyager Front-end in an instance of Google Cloud Compute Engine (used the latest versions).

Using Ubuntu 18.04 as OS.

Apache as server (even tried Nginx resulting to the same 404 error).

Pushed the files to github with the following files/directories in the .gitignore file:

```
/node_modules
/public/hot
/public/storage
/storage/*.key
/vendor
.env
.phpunit.result.cache
Homestead.json
Homestead.yaml
npm-debug.log
yarn-error.log
```

Pulled the files to another instance of Google Cloud Compute Engine.

Installed the web application using the following commands/procedures:

---

```
// created database
// installed nodejs and npm

$ sudo mkdir voyager                  // name of laravel directory
$ cd voyager
$ sudo git init
$ sudo git remote add origin https://github.com/oropezaqb/voyager.git
$ git remote
$ sudo git config credential.helper store
$ sudo git pull origin master

// configured Apache or Nginx
// setup .env file

$ sudo composer install
$ sudo php artisan key:generate
$ sudo composer dump-autoload
$ sudo php artisan migrate
$ sudo npm install
$ sudo npm run dev
$ sudo * * * * * php /path-to-your-project/artisan schedule:run >> /dev/null 2>&1
$ sudo chgrp -R www-data storage bootstrap/cache
$ sudo chmod -R ug+rwx storage bootstrap/cache
```

---

Virutal Host config:

I have this in /etc/apache2/sites-enabled/000-default.conf....

```
<VirtualHost *:80> 
  <Directory /var/www/html/voyager/public> 
    Options 
    Indexes 
    FollowSymLinks 
    MultiViews 
    AllowOverride All 
    Require all 
    granted Order allow,deny 
    allow from all 
  </Directory> 
  ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost 
  DocumentRoot /var/www/html/voyager/public 
  ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log 
  CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log 
  combined 
</VirtualHost>
```

But the home page displays a 404 error message.

Comment: Can you include you apache virual host config please and when is the URL you are attempting to get to? Also, do you have the apache mod re-rewrite enabled?

Comment: Like @Petay87 said, configuration of your vhost is most likely the problem. Second, I don't see any reason to use 'sudo' for every command here.

Comment: Also, sudo * * * * * php /path-to-your-project/artisan schedule:run >> /dev/null 2>&1 isn't correct. * * * * * php /path-to-your-project/artisan schedule:run >> /dev/null 2>&1 should be added to crontab not ran as a command. ALso make sure to change /path-to-your-project to the actual path to your directory

Comment: What is the location of config file @Petay87? Here's the URL http://34.67.240.251/. I have the apache mod re-rewrite enabled.

Comment: Thank you @dbf. I will try to study how to avoid using sudo.

Comment: You haven't configured a virtual host yet? That will be your issue. You need to create a virtual host in /etc/apache2/sites-available then use sudo a2ensite nameofconfig to make it live. These might help https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49184358/setting-document-root-for-laravel-project-on-apache-virtual-host   &&  https://laravel.io/forum/04-27-2014-laravel-virtual-hosts-apache-aaah

Comment: Okay. Will use * * * * * php /path-to-your-project/artisan schedule:run >> /dev/null 2>&1 in crontab. Thank you. I indicated DocumentRoot /var/www/html/voyager/public in /etc/apache2/sites-enabled/000-default.conf.

Comment: @Petay87 I have this in /etc/apache2/sites-enabled/000-default.conf.... <VirtualHost *:80>
    <Directory /var/www/html/voyager/public>
        Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
        AllowOverride All
        Require all granted
        Order allow,deny
        allow from all
    </Directory>

        ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
        DocumentRoot /var/www/html/voyager/public

        ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
        CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined

</VirtualHost>

Comment: When you did sudo mkdir voyager were you in the /var/www/html folder? If not, the folder was created elsewhere adn /var/www/html/voyager doesn't exist hense the 404.

Comment: @Petay87 Yes. I did sudo mkdir voyager in /var/www/html folder. I checked. I have voyager directory in /var/www/html.

Comment: @Petay87 I have a development environment that is working here http://35.202.179.114. Only when I pushed in another instance, that I get the 404 error.