# Laravel works with artisan serve but not with vhost

Tags: php, laravel, wamp, vhosts

I have installed fresh Laravel project and the welcome page shows up when using artisan serve, but when trying to access via vhost the page seems to be reloading infinitely. Im on Windows using WAMP and vhost is properly pointed to Laravels public folder (when I echo something from index.php it works). I also tried without vhost directly from localhost and same thing happens. No logs in any log neither Laravel nor apache. Any ideas what might be the problem?

Here is the vhost:

```
    <Directory "D:\Projects\PHP\psp\public">
    allow from all
    order allow,deny
    AllowOverride All
</Directory>
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerAdmin admin@psp.test
    DocumentRoot "D:\Projects\PHP\psp\public"
    ServerName psp.test
    ServerAlias www.psp.test
    ErrorLog "logs/psp.log"
    CustomLog "logs/psp-access.log" common
</VirtualHost>
```

Thanks

Comment: Show us the vhost configuration

Comment: updated the question with vhost, but as I said its working when I change index.php to just echo something and its also not working when I move project to www folder and try with localhost/psp/public

Comment: check the .htaccess file and once clear all cache and composer dump-autoload

Comment: .htaccess is good, no luck with those commands

Comment: how do you know the .htaccess is good, btw?

Comment: because its laravels default one and I have also tried the other one from the documentation. plus everything there seems fine

Comment: check this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49184358/setting-document-root-for-laravel-project-on-apache-virtual-host

Comment: tried still same...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For anyone else that might bump into this, its the PHP VERSION. Laravel docs say it needs >=7.2 and I was trying with 7.3, when I switched to 7.2 just to see if anything is different it worked... Anyway thanks for all the help.