# how to configure apache 2.4 and laravel 8 in debian 10(buster)

Tags: php, linux, laravel, debian

i need to configure:
laravel 8
php 7.4
apache 2.4
debian 10 (buster)

when i create a new project "laravel new project", i run this command, php artisan serve and all works ok, but when I configure a virtual host something goes wrong, the browser says

http://develop.test

```
   <?php

use Illuminate\Contracts\Http\Kernel;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;

define('LARAVEL_START', microtime(true));

/*
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Check If Application Is Under Maintenance
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
|
| If the application is maintenance / demo mode via the "down" command we
| will require this file so that any prerendered template can be shown
| instead of starting the framework, which could cause an exception.
|
*/

if (file_exists(__DIR__.'/../storage/framework/maintenance.php')) {
    require __DIR__.'/../storage/framework/maintenance.php';
}

/*
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Register The Auto Loader
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
|
| Composer provides a convenient, automatically generated class loader for
| this application. We just need to utilize it! We'll simply require it
| into the script here so we don't need to manually load our classes.
|
*/

require __DIR__.'/../vendor/autoload.php';

/*
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Run The Application
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
|
| Once we have the application, we can handle the incoming request using
| the application's HTTP kernel. Then, we will send the response back
| to this client's browser, allowing them to enjoy our application.
|
*/

$app = require_once __DIR__.'/../bootstrap/app.php';

$kernel = $app->make(Kernel::class);

$response = tap($kernel->handle(
    $request = Request::capture()
))->send();

$kernel->terminate($request, $response);
```

and the aplication is not in maintenance mode, i never run command like php artisan down.
with that problem i try to run php artisan down and next php artisan up, but nothing happen, the error is always there.

here is my apache conf file

```
 <VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerAdmin yvasquez@develop.test
    ServerName develop.test
    ServerAlias www.develop.test
    DocumentRoot /var/www/html/develop/public


    <Directory /var/www/html/develop/public>
        Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
        AllowOverride All
        ReWriteEngine On
        Require all granted
        <FilesMatch \.php$>
            # Change this "proxy:unix:/path/to/fpm.socket"
            # if using a Unix socket
            # SetHandler "proxy:fcgi://127.0.0.1:9000"
        </FilesMatch>
        
    </Directory>

    ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/develop-error.log
    CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/develop-access.log combined

</VirtualHost>
```

I followed this article for this conf file [Setting document root for Laravel project on Apache virtual host](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49184358/setting-document-root-for-laravel-project-on-apache-virtual-host)

Comment: Your <FilesMatch \.php$> is empty, contains only comments.

Comment: thats right but i do not what i must put there

Comment: Maybe nothing, but then remove the FilesMatch section. Else uncomment the SetHandler directive.

Comment: Gerard H. Pille thanks for your patience,
I follow your recommendatios.
i delete FilesMatch section and uncomment de SetHanlder too.
I try with a new project and the problem is the same and always there.

When i run "php artisan serve" all works ok but with a little problem, when i loading images in storage, the image not found because the url image is not with the 8000 port

Comment: "the browser says http://develop.test"  What does the browser "say" ?  You are the only one who can access develop.test.

Comment: What is the 8000 port you mention?  Develop.test can only be found on port 80:    <VirtualHost *:80> !!

Comment: when i run "php artisan serve" it enables localhost:8000 and all works ok, but  the application dont load images that are en Storage folder because it points to http://localhost/storage/images/.... and the application not put por 8000.00

i am working with "php artisan serve" because my php  configuration don't work.
, remember in my problem i can't  run develop.test.

Comment: firefox on http://develop.test says 
make(Kernel::class); $response = tap($kernel->handle( $request = Request::capture() ))->send(); $kernel->terminate($request, $response);

Comment: When Laravel is running on port 8000, the SetHandler  "proxy:fcgi://127.0.0.1:9000" should refer to 8000, not 9000.  Also, do you find anything else in your apache configuration referring to PHP ?

Comment: concerning the images not loading, I would change " 'url' => env('APP_URL', 'http://localhost')," in app.php and add the port number.

Comment: thanks for your answer, i will work with "php artisan serve" for now,

Also, do you find anything else in your apache configuration referring to PHP ?
all is by default

Comment: "all is by default " Is that a "no"? It seems develop.test is not configured to handle php. No php = no laravel.

Comment: I recently install xampp 8.0.0-2
now, i am working on it very well with the same project,
and I will be left wondering how the configuration is without xampp.
Thanks for your patience Gerard H. Pille.
I am so sorry for my english

Comment: I have no problems with your english.  Es mucho mejor que mi español, si eso es lo que hablas.  This morning, just past midnight here, I finally managed to configure Apache, PHP-FPM and Laravel to work together.  I will try to document my configuration in an answer below.  It took me two days because I have never used Laravel before.

Comment: gracias,
well, I wait patiently for your answer, thanks a lot,

Comment: You are (a) very (good) patient.

Comment: "Something goes wrong" is pretty broad, what does that mean? Please share more details by editing your question

Answer (score 1):

I added the FQDN to /etc/hosts

```
127.0.0.1   localhost me.me.be example.me.be
```

and then a rather simple apache configuration

```
<VirtualHost _default_:*>
        ServerName example.me.be
        ServerAdmin me@me.be
        DocumentRoot /var/www/html/example.me.be/public/
        DirectoryIndex /index.php index.php
        ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error_example.log
        CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access_example.log combined
        ProxyPassMatch "^/(.*\.php(\?.*)?)$" "fcgi://127.0.0.1:9000/var/www/html/example.me.be/public/$1"
        <Directory /var/www/html/example.me.be/public/>
                AllowOverride ALL
        </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

/var/www/html/example.me.be is where Laravel has been "installed" - without any use of composer or "laravel install", just download a create-project from php-download.com.

127.0.0.1:9000 is where php-fpm is listening.  This may need a change to its configuration, if by default it only listens on a socket.

/etc/php/7.4/fpm/pool.d/www.conf:

```
listen = 9000
```

Laravel needed some extensions to be activated (and installed if not).

/etc/php/7.4/fpm/php.ini:

```
extension=pdo
extension=mysqlnd
extension=pdo_mysql
extension=json
extension=tokenizer
```

pdo_mysql depends on mysqlnd, some debugging was needed to find this.  Also, make sure you have a page with phpinfo(), very enlightening.  MySQL is no must, it's MariaDB anyhow,  PostgreSQL works too.